# Is it possible to protect own photos on instagram using NFTs?

Tags: copyright, instagram

I am an amateur photographer who usually posts the best pics on his own instagram page.
Since I often put an effort and even produce accepatable pics that I think might be used by other people (e.g. to promote the area), I started thinking I should protect my own work.

Is it possible to tokenize them before being uploaded on instagram so as to maintain authorship?
Does it really make a difference when the pic is “stolen” on the web that you are the owner according to an NFT provider?

Answer (score 3):

As you have correctly realised, you have drunk a little too much of the crypto Kool-Aid.

> Does it really make a difference when the pic is “stolen” on the web that you are the owner according to an NFT provider?

No. If you want to protect your photos, stick a watermark or similar on them.